# determine user control parameter at runtime

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control which I call like this:

```
<MyNamespace:MyControl runAt="server" ID="foo" />
```

Is there any way I can determine the ID parameter at run-time and pass it in?

Comment: Pass it in to what? You have the ID defined there. Are you looking for the ClientID?

Comment: I'd re-ask the question stating what you are trying to accomplish -- needing to set the ID at runtime usually indicates you realy need to get the id somewhere. And there are good ways of doing that.

Comment: I want to create a set of user controls numbered sequentially, i.e. MyControl1, MyControl2, etc. and I don't know until runtime how many there will be

Comment: Why do they need to be numbered sequentially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a technique that works even in a loop!

```
<script runat="server">
void AddTextBox(int i)
{
    var ctrl = new TextBox() { ID = i.ToString()};
    ctrl.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(Response.Output));
}
</script>
<%
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

%>
    Control Rendering Begin
    <br />
<%
        AddTextBox(i);
        %>
        <br />
        Control Rendering Ends
        <br />
        <%
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward; so long as it's constructed properly (using **LoadControl** for **UserControls**, for instance) and early enough for life-cycle initialization, you can assign the ID at will and retrieve the control using **FindControl** on the appropriate **NamingContainer**.

Here's a basic sample:

```
  protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            Controls.Add(new Literal() { ID = "MyControl" + i, Text = i.ToString() });

        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            Response.Write(((Literal)FindControl("MyControl" + i)).Text + "<br/>");
    }
```

...that outputs:

```
0
1
2
3
4
01234
```

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy I've found is to set the control's OnInit callback, and use the codebehind to set the property value.

Of course, if you're in a template context, that's a different story.

**Edit**

Sorry, I read too quickly and didn't realize that you're trying to set the ID property itself. The point of the ID property is to uniquely identify this particular instance of the control, within the context of its parent control. Whatever you're trying to accomplish by setting this ID to some custom value is probably better accomplished using another strategy. Can you provide more information about the bigger problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: The problem is I don't even know how many of them there will be on a page until run-time!

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to do this programatically, then add the control dynamically in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here's the solution I ended up using:

```
<% Dim ctrlName As String %>

....

<% ctrlId = "whatever" 'need to wait until here to figure out the ID %>

....

<% mySpan.Controls.Add(New MyNamespace.MyControl() _
     With { .ID = ctrlId }) %>

<span runat="server" id="mySpan" />
```

**EDIT:**

This won't work in a loop... see my better answer that works even in a loop.